# jquery object calling a function within itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below I am calling  loadAuthorsList function which should then pass its information on to the loadTemplate function.  But I am being told by firebug that 'this.loadTemplate' is not a function.  Why and how do I fix it?

```
 var LI = {
        sFI: x,
     loadAuthorsList: function () {
            myApp.showPleaseWait();
            //for later
            $('#records_table').find('tr:gt(0)').remove();
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: this.sFI.getServiceRoot('A'),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {},
                beforeSend: this.sFI.setModuleHeaders,
                success: function (data) {
                    this.loadTemplate('AuthorTemplate', '#author_records', data)
                },
                complete: function () {

                }
            });
        },

    loadTemplate: function (templateName, selectorName, inputData) {
            var jsPath = this.serviceFrameInstructors.getServiceRoot('LearnoogleInstructors');
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: jsPath.slice(0, -4) + 'js/templates/' + templateName + '.html',// + intArea,
                cache: false,
                success: function (value) {
                    var personTemplate = $.templates(value);
                    var html = personTemplate.render(inputData);
                    $(selectorName).html(html);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: You're not within the Object context. You can use `LI.loadTemplate` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because in success callback `this` points to another object (XHR). You can bind context explicitly with [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for example:

```
success: function (data) {
    this.loadTemplate('AuthorTemplate', '#author_records', data)
}.bind(this),
```

Or simpler, you can store reference to correct context in variable:

```
var self = this;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: this.sFI.getServiceRoot('A'),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    beforeSend: this.sFI.setModuleHeaders,
    success: function (data) {
        self.loadTemplate('AuthorTemplate', '#author_records', data)
    },
    complete: function () {

    }
});
```

Or one more options: use can use jQuery [`context`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) setting to provide context for AJAX callbacks:

```
context: this,
success: function (data) {
    this.loadTemplate('AuthorTemplate', '#author_records', data)
},
```

Comment: is this a good way to do this?

Comment: @braindice - it's convention in JS to solve this simple, commonly encountered circumstance.

Comment: @braindice I'd recommend that you use bind. This page will teach you all about it as well as the intricacies of function calling within JavaScript https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: `Function.prototype.bind` is not supported by IE8<. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: @RaulFernandez And for IE8 there is `$.proxy`. But better to use `context: this` setting. I would go with `bind` or self.

Comment: @RaulFernandez - that's why `self` is the common convention. But depending on what environment you need to support, `bind` is perfectly fine as well.